# Showing data after data stored inside storage

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-storage

Im using

```
php artisan storage:link
```

I already store my data in "public/storage/project" using

```
$ft->store('project');
```

But when i try to show it, or put it on link, the image did not show up or the link display wrong page.

```
<p><span>Lokasi File : </span><span><a href="{{ asset('storage/project/'.$row->file_name_att) }}">asdsad</a></span></p>
```

Or

```
<p><span>Lokasi File : </span><span><img src="{{ asset('storage/project/'.$row->file_name_att) }}"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you aren't storing the file in public disk. You need to do:

```php
$ft->store('project', ['disk' => 'public']);
```

This way, the file will be stored in the public disk and will be available for you via `asset()` helper.

Comment: I already change my code and when i insert my data, it gave me this location "project/NX8WiJ1qnLFupowrItKNOOMEE71LMy5uxFJQ0rLj.jpeg" for the new image inside storage. How can i show it ?

Comment: Can you see `NX8WiJ1qnLFupowrItKNOOMEE71LMy5uxFJQ0rLj.jpeg` file in `storage/app/public/project`?

Comment: Yes theres image by that name in that folder.

Comment: `Storage::disk('public')->url('project/NX8WiJ1qnLFupowrItKNOOMEE71LMy5uxFJQ0rLj.jpeg)` or just `asset('storage/project/NX8WiJ1qnLFupowrItKNOOMEE71LMy5uxFJQ0rLj.jpeg')` is what you need. p.s. use dynamic filename in place of `NX8WiJ1qnLFupowrItKNOOMEE71LMy5uxFJQ0rLj.jpeg`

Comment: It works, thanks ! but i guess i need to use encrypted name used by laravel storage, cant call original value name.

Comment: @user2977799 yes, for consistency, use Laravel's generate filename. You will get the stored name by doing `$savedFile = $ft->store('project', ['disk' => 'public']);`